# ClickOnce overwriting .exe.config with old version from 'obj' directory during publish

Tags: c#, clickonce

I'm working on an old ClickOnce app that's being updated for the first time in a couple of years.

As the title states, for some reason the ClickOnce publish is overwriting the generated ApplicationName.exe.config file with an out of date version located in the \obj\ subdirectory of the project.

This is causing a couple of issues:

Firstly, the hash fails on that file when trying to install the ClickOnce. My assumption is that Visual Studio is generating the .exe.config file as usual and generating a hash for the generated version, but then copying this other version over the top thus breaking the hash (there are no pre or post build events in the project).

Secondly, even if I disable hashing on that file, any changes I make to app.config don't make it to the published version as the config is overwritten by this old \obj\ version. If I delete the file from the \obj\ folder, when trying to run the ClickOnce setup it tells me it's missing the file and aborts.

I've done a text content search of the entire project directory and can't find any mention of this \obj\ file anywhere, but it has to be there because the bug is reproducible on a different PC that's pulled the project via source control.

I'm baffled because I thought that the \obj\ folder was just used for VS's local working files, and I can't understand why, how or where in the config files something like this could be set. Help!

Edit: Other stuff that's been tried:

- Cleaning the project
- Publishing to a fresh location in ClickOnce
- Wiping the \obj\ directory (except this one config file)

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project?

Comment: I have, will add that to the question though, thanks!